# Generating same class with different variables merged from different XSDs in JAXB

Tags: java, eclipse, jaxb

I have two schemas as mentioned below. I am using JAXB in eclipse to create classes from schemas and I want single class "Object" to have both x and y.
 But when trying to generate the classes from xsd in eclipse, once I create class "Object" using a.xsd, it is being replaced/Overwritten when trying to create classes from b.xsd. Please advise.

a.xsd:

```
<message>
<event>
<object>
<x>..</x>
</object>
</event>
</message>
```

b.xsd

```
<message>
<event>
<object>
<y>..</y>
</object>
</event>
</message>
```